# Not able to click the Deployment link

Tags: java, selenium

Not able to click the Deployment link  button through selenium. How do I click on the Environment button?

Code is below:

```
<a title="Deployments, Level 1, 2 of 6" class="tree_link" 
    id="linkAppDeploymentsControlPage" href="/console/console.portal?_nfpb=true&amp;_pageLabel=AppDeploymentsControlPage" 
    onkeypress="checkKeyStroke(event);" onmouseover="mouseOverCall('AppDeploymentsControlPage', 'popup');" 
    onmouseout="mouseOutCall('AppDeploymentsControlPage');" 
    oncontextmenu="return startDisplayPopup('AppDeploymentsControlPage', 'popup', event);">Deployments</a>

<span id="placeholderAppDeploymentsControlPage"></span>

<a title="Deployments, Level 1, 2 of 6" href="/console/console.portal?_nfpb=true&amp;_pageLabel=AppDeploymentsControlPage">
    <img id="iconAppDeploymentsControlPage" src="images/spacer.gif" align="absbottom" alt="" 
        border="0" onmouseover="mouseOverCall('AppDeploymentsControlPage', 'popup');" 
        onmouseout="mouseOutCall('AppDeploymentsControlPage');" oncontextmenu="return startDisplayPopup('AppDeploymentsControlPage', 'popup', event);" 
        title="Deployments">
</a>

<img id="iconAppDeploymentsControlPage" src="images/spacer.gif" align="absbottom" alt="" 
        border="0" onmouseover="mouseOverCall('AppDeploymentsControlPage', 'popup');" 
        onmouseout="mouseOutCall('AppDeploymentsControlPage');" oncontextmenu="return startDisplayPopup('AppDeploymentsControlPage', 'popup', event);" 
        title="Deployments">
```

I have tried using the code options below, but still it's not reflecting my changes or not able to click on deployment link:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("iconAppDeploymentsControlPa‌​ge")).click(); 
//driver.findElement(By.className("formButton")).click(); 
//driver.findElement(By.className("iconAppDeploymentsContr‌​olPage")).click(); 
//driver.findElement(By.className("tree_link")).click(); 
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@ src='images/shim.gif']")).click(); 
//driver.findElement(By.className("images/spacer.gif")).cl‌​ick(); 
//driver.findElement(By.className("Deployments")).click(); 
//driver.findElement(By.className("wlsc-titlebar-button-pa‌​nel")).click();
```

Comment: using all the listed code but still not hitting deployment link

Comment: Share your html, nobody could help you with these info you gave us.

Comment: I've made an edit to fix your code formatting so your `html` will show, and I've put your code in the question as well. In addition, Please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to format your code to make it easy for others to understand the issue and be able to help :)

Comment: @SatishMishraUS there is nothing in your `html` with the class name 'Deployments', can you clarify which element in that `html` you're trying to click?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to click the link with the text "Deployments" you can do this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Deployments']")).click();
```